# let $ \ \ 0<a \leq b \leq c \in \mathbb{R}$ then prove that :

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, buffalo-way

let $ \ \ 0<a \leq b \leq c  \in \mathbb{R}$ 
then prove that :

$$\frac{(c-a)^2}{6c}\leq \frac{a+b+c}{3}-\frac{3}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}$$

---

I do not know where to start please help me !

Comment: How did you get 2 upvotes if you didn't show any effort? You don't have other accounts where you upvote a question of your own?

Comment: @AnonymousI you feel like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4) showed more effort?

Comment: That's more a recreational type of question whereas this question is more like a contest inequality problem. The questioner should have posted some efforts even if it was leading nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

Your inequality is true!

We need to prove that
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}-\frac{3abc}{ab+ac+bc}\geq\frac{(c-a)^2}{6c}$$ or
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}c(a-b)^2}{ab+ac+bc}\geq\frac{(c-a)^2}{2c}$$ or
$$2c(a-b)^2+2a(b-c)^2\geq\left(\frac{ab}{c}+a-b\right)(c-a)^2.$$
Now, by C-S
$$2c(a-b)^2+2a(b-c)^2=2ac\left(\frac{(b-a)^2}{a}+\frac{(c-b)^2}{c}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{2ac(b-a+c-b)^2}{a+c}=\frac{2ac(c-a)^2}{a+c}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$2ac\geq(a+c)\left(\frac{ab}{c}+a-b\right)$$ or
$$c^2a+c^2b\geq a^2b+a^2c,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: I did not understand that:$$2c(a-b)^2+2a(b-c)^2=2ac\left(\frac{(b-a)^2}{a}+\frac{(c-b)^2}{c}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{2ac(b-a+c-b)^2}{a+c}=\frac{2ac(c-a)^2}{a+c}$$

Comment: @Almot1960 It's Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. For positives $b_i$ we have: $\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+...+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}\geq\frac{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2}{b_1+b_2+...+b_n}.$

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the denominators and moving all terms to the left we have to prove that
$$-a^3b-a^3c+3a^2bc+4a^2c^2+2ab^2c-11abc^2+ac^3+2b^2c^2+bc^3\geq 0$$
Setting
$$b=a+u,c=a+u+v$$ with $$u,v\geq 0$$ this inequality is equivalent to
$$a^2(u-v)^2+4au^3+4au^2v+2auv^2+2av^3+3u^3+7u^3v+5u^2v^2+uv^3\geq 0$$
which is true.