# Prove $ \frac{(c-a)^{2}}{6c} \le \frac{a+b+c}{3} - \frac{3}{ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}+ \frac{1}{c}}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given real numbers $c \ge b \ge a>0$, prove that

$$ \frac{(c-a)^{2}}{6c} \le \frac{a+b+c}{3} - \frac{3}{ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}}$$

*using well-known inequality

---

Other solution without famous inequality: I already know a solution that uses only algebraic manipulation here https://youtu.be/A0Qv8H1YDsc

But I am trying a solution that uses AM and HM inequality, because the RHS seems familiar to AM and HM.

**Attempt**:
Notice obviously that
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3} \ge (abc)^{1/3} $$
$$ - \frac{3}{ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}} \ge -(abc)^{1/3}
$$

But using these only imply the RHS of the problem is non-negative. While the left hand side can be positive depending on $a$,$c$.

Next, by write the 2nd term of RHS of the problem as

$$ \frac{3}{ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}} = \frac{3abc}{ab +bc +ac}$$

the inequality to be proven is

$$ \frac{(c-a)^{2}}{2} (a + b + \frac{ab}{c}) \le (a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)-9abc$$

By AM-GM the RHS is bigger than or equal to:
$$ 9(abc)^{1/3} (abc)^{2/3} - 9abc =0$$
too.
So can we solved this problem using well-known inequality?

Comment: If you use the AM-HM inequality, then the RHS would become 0. How exactly are you thinking about using it?

Comment: 1.https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1234734p6264772  2.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493515/let-0a-leq-b-leq-c-in-mathbbr-then-prove-that?noredirect=1

Comment: But none of these use AM-HM